# What can I do when my boss is forcing me to wear an inappropriate style of dress?

Tags: india, sexual-harassment, sexism

I am working as a private secretary (for CEO) of a small company in India. Even though the company is small, it is very well established with really good salaries and benefits.

I usually go to meetings with my boss. Now he is insisting that I wear open clothes (specially chest area) when going to these meetings.  He thinks he can easily negotiate a deal with the other party, when they are looking at me.

I am very uncomfortable wearing these type of clothes and I did mention this to him. He is asking me why did I accept the job on the first place if I am not comfortable with this. My contract did say that I will need to wear clothes as per company needs. I did not think it will be a big deal and signed anyway.

Is there a way to reject wearing those types of clothes and keep my job at the same time?

Comment: We can give you a general script to follow to professionally communicate to your boss your unwillingness to wear such revealing clothing but we can't know whether that will have the effect you're looking for. Your boss may consider this a job requirement and then your only recourse would be to escalate to HR or find a lawyer. But both those options depend on your company culture and how well the relevant employment laws for your location cover you when it comes to sexism and discrimination.

Comment: You probably assumed that "wear clothes as per company needs" would be within the range of appropriate business clothing. That might be a point you could use in discussing this with your boss.

Comment: Not clear if he is requesting or enforcing.   Are you wearing revealing clothes to his satisfaction at this time?

Comment: If you are already wearing business attires, I would consider unreasonable to enforce how open the chest area of your top should be. How exactly did he approach you?

Comment: "Now he is insisting that I wear open clothes (specially chest area) when going to these meetings. He thinks he can easily negotiate a deal with the other party, when they are looking at me." His offers must be really shitty if he needs that make a deal.

Comment: He's a sleaze, but he was also kind of up-front about the requirements of the job. Trying to wiggle out of it after having signed a contract is tricky, especially in a country that doesn't have robust legislation protecting employee's rights. I think you're going to have to either acquiesce, or quit.

Comment: " My contract did say that I will need to wear clothes as per company needs." I would take that to mean a pants suit, not a tank top. Maybe I'm just naive.

Answer (score 7):

> My contract did say that I will need to wear clothes as per company
>   needs

If it is in the clause of the contract, it shouldn't have been taken lightly because like your boss said *why did I accept the job in the first place if I am not comfortable with this*. but you can always see what that certain **clause** says, does it say *revealing, open, short, tight or elegant*? from there you take on the below advice (if you prefer)

Now, if we talk about the mentality of south Asian people (and no offense to any) they have a strong opinion "If it shows, it will sell" and that has sadly been objectified it into women because you know the reason. In your situation which might tick your boss off if pushed because he can say it was in the clause, but as a man perspective (me), you can dress well. Revealing clothes isn't always a "deal maker".

> Is there a way to reject wearing those types of clothes and keep my
>   job at the same time?

You can/might turn this around by dressing more elegant, look for good premium dresses, good salon for good haircut and taken professional makeup classes on youtube, this (might) will change the mind of your boss from "open" clothes, but if he insists, it is a sign that says that he is trying to sell his business by objectifying a women which might not be ok with you or other women.

The above assumption is based on if I was a boss and I had a secretary, I would rather ask for to dress more elegantly, executively and premium, if I had to ask my secretary to wear revealing clothes, then it is my thought process that is wrong and if things might go beyond business with secretaries (it is in history).

Comment: Spend more on salon and fancy clothes does not seem fair.

Comment: @Paparazzi The OP is not ok with the fact that wearing tight or revealing clothes. I advise her the best I can and If I was a boss and I would as of that because if her boss is trying to make her skin reveal, it is time to quit.

Comment: Your comment about ‘South Asian People’ IS offensive. Your disclaimer does not make it any better. Does western world not practice ‘show and sell’? Some would think more than anyone.  Moreover your answer would have been valid even without that remark. Whether it is right or wrong is different argument altogether.

Comment: @PagMax I am south asian and my assumption is based on the culture I was surrounded with. How can I blame west when all I know about west if through media or Trump, movies aren't real.

Comment: @cookieMonster I didn't say you are blaming west. I meant one can do it with similar logic as yours. I am also south asian. I do not think people believe in "Show and Sell" anymore than anyone from some other geographical region.